# Docker: http requests from a container to other stalled

Tags: node.js, docker, http, express, fetch

I use VPS for testing my web apps online. And I use Docker to run many web apps in the same server. Here is my

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  gateway:
    build:
      context: ./gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    networks:
      erealm:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.2

  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 4lf483t0
    networks:
      erealm:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.3

  phpmyadmin:
    image: nazarpc/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=10.5.0.3:3306
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 1234:80
    networks:
      erealm:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.4

  static:
    build:
      context: ./static
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    networks:
      erealm:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

  onlinecv:
    build:
      context: ./onlinecv
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 81:3000
    networks:
      erealm:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.10

  speeqapi:
    build:
      context: ./speeq/api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_SERVER: 10.5.0.3
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_USER: xxxxxxxxxx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxxxxxxx
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      erealm:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.20

  speeqfe:
    build:
      context: ./speeq/fe
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      REACT_APP_API_SERVER: 10.5.0.20:3000
      REACT_APP_STATIC_SERVER: 10.5.0.5:3000
    ports:
      - 82:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - static
      - speeqapi
    networks:
      erealm:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.21

networks:
  erealm:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/24
```

The main ideia behind this scheme is having only HTTP ports open to the world, while all necessary services run protected by Docker internal network, unaccesible to the world outside.

I use the gateway service to map the HTTP requests coming for the different apps to different ports. So, I have my online CV mapped to CNAME cv.eddealmeida.net and this Speeq app mapped to CNAME speeq.eddealmeida.net in my DNS zone, both pointing to this server. When my server receives a request to http://cv.eddealmeida.net or http://speeq.eddealmeida.net, the Node/Express-based gateway application (listening to port 80) splits the HOST paraments of the request an applies a simple mapping to send the requests to port 81 and 82 respectively.

Well, everything is running fine, but for the internal requests. First I had a problem with nternal name resolution, which I solved by giving IPs to all services, as you may see.

Now my internal requests are going to their correct places, but... the fetch requests made by the speeq frontend are stalling. They just keep stalling, over and over again. I tested the API using `curl` and everything is fine, it aswers correctly my command line requests. So, there is no problem with my API / Database connection or something like that. Google Chrome gave me this [explanation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#timing-explanation), but I can't see me fitting in any of the cases mentioned.

Have someone ever lived a situation like this to give me a hint? I've been fighting this for the last 24 hours and run out of ideas. I double-checked everything and it still won't work.

Comment: Couple of ques: Where are you running the curl commands? On the localhost or inside one of the containers?

Comment: As I understand, you just want all your apps to get connected, right? Then you can use the `links` directive and use the service name instead of static IPs

Comment: @ManishDash Localhost. But thanks for the suggestion. I'll try them inside the speeq frontend container to see what happens.

Comment: Because Dockerr documentation says this `links` directive is about to be removed and I am looking for a long term solution.

Comment: Try pinging inside the containers to see if they are interconnected correctly. Then curl to check whether connections are working. If they do not, I suspect you should `expose` your internal ports

Comment: I may run `curl http://10.5.0.20:3000/users` inside the frontend container and the result is OK. I may also ping 10.5.0.20, the API serve from inside it. But still, when I `fetch` the results from the same server, it stalls.

Comment: My internal ports are exposed in the respective Dockerfiles. And yes, I may ping the containers from one another. It seems to me now this may be a browser thing.

Comment: By `fetch` you mean a GET request? Can you try the same inside the container using curl?

Comment: Static IPs are not a good approach with containers. If I understood correctly, you're running the containers on the same host, right? You can try to create a custom Docker network and define the containers in the same network. Then you can access them through the container names, using it as a host name, instead of the IPs.

Comment: By `fetch` I mean usign the  Javascript `fetch`API to perform GETs, POSTs and other tyes of requests. And yes, I may use curl and receive correct responses from inside the containers. I mentioned this is one of my comments.

Comment: @Milkncookiez I am assuming you haven't read the `docker-compose.yml`, because this is exactly what I'm doing, defining the containers inside the same custom network named erealm. I was using the internal name resolution and having problems with it. I also mention this in the question. This is why I opted for the IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have few assumptions that might help.

1- Regarding the usage of IPs, I would suggest trying to use [network aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) instead of IPs and this is a long-term solution

2- I can see that you are using ReactJS as a front-end which is a client side - I am assuming that you are using static files after building your React application - in this case you need to expose the backend/api to public ip through port mapping or using domain name points to a public ip where your api is listening or any similar method in order to make the front-end application able to reach it when you open it from the browser (which is a different device in your case). So if `speeqfe` is a reactjs frontend you need to change the environment variables value which points to the other containers to a public ip in order to make it work properly after building the static files

Comment: I tried using aliases, but I only got an error message about hostname resolution. It seems Docker isnt't resolving hostnames correctly.

Comment: I mapped the API exposed port to a public IP. It worked fine, but this meas I would have to implement some security measues to avoid public access to my API. Something like restrincting access to the frontend public URL.

Comment: Anyway, your answer solves my problem and I am going to accept it.

Comment: Yes you need to add a security layer maybe allow certain IPs and token auth and so on. Don't forget to add the bounty :D

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help anyone, in my case the issue was that my Nginx config (IF you even use Nginx here) was pointing to http://localhost:1234, after changing this to http://127.0.0.1:1234 it worked!